# Javascript - how to change innerText of label while not wiping out the input

Tags: javascript, html, input, label, innertext

I would like to ask how - by Javascript - to **change the label `innerText`** of radio buttons (see code below) **while not wiping out the input tag inside**. Label innerText here means "*Button-Label-X*".

I've tried to diagnose the label style via elements of `document.getElementsByClassName("radio-label")`, including

- textContent: "Button-Label-X"
- innerText :"Button-Label-X"
- outerText :"Button-Label-X"

then assigned new string value (ex. "Button-Label-Y") to them. However, all those ways lead to the same result: the input disappeared, only new value left. Anyone has any idea here?

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="optradio"> Button-Label-X </label>
</div>
```

Of course, I could do the way around by putting input tag outside of label, then everything is solved. But, for that case, I must set `id` for input and "for:id" for label. And it becomes tedious work for the case of 05 buttons instead of 01 one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can access to the text part from [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes). Once you have it, you can change the text by set the property [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to the wanted text.

Like this:

```js
function changeLabelText(label, text) {
  var children = label.childNodes;
  [].forEach.call(children, function(child) {
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {
      child.textContent = text;
    }
  });
}

var label = document.querySelector('label');
changeLabelText(label, 'blabla');
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="optradio"> Button-Label-X </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Your suggestion lead me to correct answer. I just changed the childNodes[ ].data or childNodes[ ].textContent of document.getElementsByClassName("radio-label"), then it worked perfectly. Thank you!